# Which one is more correct and natural: "in that lane" or "on that lane" when talking about trucking?

Tags: prepositions

Would you tell me which one is more correct and natural: *in that lane* or *on that lane* when talking about trucking? For example:

> We have a driver who can move the load from New-York to California, but the rate won't be low **in**/**on** that lane.

I'm aware that when we are talking about actual road lanes we use *in*, but what about that context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about lanes of a road (for example, a dual carriageway has two 'lanes'), we do say "in lane". In fact, road signs in the UK on motorways say "GET IN LANE" when specific lane discipline applies.

However, I don't believe that is what the context of your example means. A 'trucking lane' (or 'transportation lane') is a term referring to a mapped route of transportation between two places, in which case it would surely be "on lane", as we would use 'on' for a route.

Comment: For the record, in the US (probably relevant since the op mentions New York and California) we'd say "get in your lane" or "pick a lane". The zero article isn't used in this context in the US.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, the word "lane" appears to mean "route". I am unfamiliar with this usage of the word "lane", and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lane) has no mention of this definition of "lane".

I'm therefore guessing "lane" is a typo for "line", which is a common trucking word for "route":

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/line):
> **3 c** the course or direction of something in motion : ROUTE